# is there a dataset/database contains false and true negative and positive statistics for some specific disease?

Tags: data-request, medical, disease

I would like to compute a set of statistics consists of 4 following items:

1. false negative
2. true negative
3. false positive
4. true positive

Is there a public dataset/database for some specific disease could be used for this?

Comment: This belongs in Open Data SE

Comment: What data fields do you need? Please read [this guide to writing a good data request](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look) and update your question with the necessary information.